# Parse json to necessary object

Tags: java, android, json

In my Android app I have `json`, which looks like :

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "RowIndex": "0",
            "NameValue": {
                "Name": "PropertyName1",
                "Value": "PropertyValue1"
            }
        }{
            "RowIndex": "1",
            "NameValue": {
                "Name": "PropertyName2",
                "Value": "PropertyValue2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to parce this json to object, which looks like:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String PropertyName1;
    public String PropertyName2;
}
```

And result after parsing should be:

```
public String PropertyName1 = "PropertyValue1";
public String PropertyName2 = "PropertyValue2";
```

Basically, the first json is equivalent of:

```
{
    "PropertyName1" : "PropertyValue1",
    "PropertyName2" : "PropertyValue2"
}
```

Question: How can I parce first json without usage `swith/case` to search for the necessary Property?

Comment: The JSON looks awkward. Did you make it? If so, I would suggest to use other naming scheme. It's more natural to do "PropertyName2": "PropertyValue2". It makes parsing a lot easier.

Comment: @RvdK, I know, but unfortunatelly, I can't change it (I use an existing API). For now I have only 1 idea - to create new json (like second in my post) from existing (like first in my post), and only after that - parce second json to object.

Comment: @downvoters, please leave a comment...

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to go down the dark path of reflection I'm afraid.
you can parse the json into an intermediary object which has a map for namevalue.

then you use the below code (ofcourse just copy paste the bits you need) to loop over the map of key/value pairs. for each key look up the field you want, and set it. If you're guaranteed only to need to set public variables then you can use getFields and can skip the setAccessible.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        Class<?> classObject = myClass.getClass();

//        Field fields[] = classObject.getFields(); // if you want to get only public fields.
        Field fields[] = classObject.getDeclaredFields(); // any field
        for(Field f : fields) {
            System.out.println(f.getName());
            try {
                // if member is private: security managers may object but the default java allows it
                f.setAccessible(true);
                f.set(myClass, "abc");
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // handle access exception:
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("prop 1: " + myClass.PropertyName1);
        System.out.println("prop 2: " + myClass.PropertyName2);
    }


    public static class MyClass {
        public String PropertyName1;
        private String PropertyName2;
    }
}
```

Actually.. there is a non-reflect way but that will replace your implementation of the object you have.

If you change your class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String PropertyName1;
    public String PropertyName2;
}
```

to

```
public class MyClass {
    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public void setProperties(Map<String, String> props) { this.properties = props; }
    public String getPropertyName1() {
        return lookupProperty("PropertyName1");
    }
    public String getPropertyName2() {
        return lookupProperty("PropertyName2");
    }
    private String lookupProperty(String property) {
        if (properties.containsKey(property) {
            return properties.get(property);
        } else { 
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

then you could parse the name value map into a map, and construct a myclass with it.
just listing it for completeness, though changing your domain model to fit a json input is not ideal.

I would recommend either way to do the input parsing, and then copy over the model into your actual domain object rather than using the json-model in your application. that way if the json model ever changes, your domain model will not change.

Comment: I like the second half of this answer a lot. Using the `Map` is a really good idea.

Answer (score 1):

One method I can think of (which doesn't sound too great) is to actually make an object that matches the JSON response you get back. Then, map THAT `NameValue` object to `MyClass`

So, something like

```
public class NameValue {
   public string Name;
   public String Value;

   public MyClass getMyClass(){
         MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
         myClass.PropertyName2 = Value;
         return myClass;
   }
}
```

You can come up with a better way to map it, obviously. But this is just an example of something I might do if I was given a response JSON I didn't particularly care for. You can similarly reverse it (have `MyClass` be able to create a `NameValue` object) so you can send data back in the correct format.